# Is my router/modem hacked or compromised?

Tags: router, wireless-router, php

Comcast gave me a gateway (Model: [Arris TG862G/CT](http://www.arrisi.com/support/documentation/user_guides/_docs/TG862G-CT_User_Guide_Standard1-0.pdf)), and I was in the web interface  setting up a static IP. I clicked Connected Devices (which has worked previously) and I got a blank white page (the source page is php).

Curious why this page was suddenly failing, I typed in "10.0.0.1/index.php" just to see if an index existed, and it does... sort of. 
The resulting index was a list of all the pages on the router's web interface, but with a different domain, ie:

```
http://slemoine.dory.chester.contentproject.com/software.php
http://slemoine.dory.chester.contentproject.com/hardware.php
http://slemoine.dory.chester.contentproject.com/battery.php
http://slemoine.dory.chester.contentproject.com/lan.php
http://slemoine.dory.chester.contentproject.com/wifi.php
```

I immediately thought "hacked!", because on top of the weird index this router has had terrible wifi right from the get go (2mbps - 10mbps wireless, 100mbps wired based on speedtests).

So does anyone know why these external, non-secure (http not https) domain would be in my router's index.php?

Comment: First of all tell us the full model of the device and whether you did something like upgrading firmware or stuff with it

Comment: Disconnect the internet (WAN connection). Factory reset and reconfigure the router. Set a new admin password and disable WAN router configuration **before** reconnecting to the internet.

Comment: @Ashtray - I haven't messed with the router's firmware or anything. All I've done is set some static IPs for raspberry pi and the like. Added the router's model # to original question.

Comment: @DavidPostill - Good call, will do

Comment: Have you tried to open that URL (10.0.0.1) from diffrent machine? Maybe problem is in your computer, not router?

Comment: Performed a factory reset, changed pw, and I have the same links in the index.php. My connected devices link is back though. Maybe contentproject.com  was involved with building the web interface for the router? CMS developers or something? Doesn't seem like a hack at least

Answer (score 0):

No, your modem has not been hacked. Based of my own experience, if you go to /index.php you will get that index page. If you just go to / then you get a login page.

And just for fun, if you go to /styleguide.php you get a nice style guide ;)

Comment: Yep, you can click "show more comments" above to see my outcome. I am assuming that Comcast contracted a company to build their modem/router UI, and the company that built that UI is no longer active at that domain. Still, very strange practice to have the domains hard coded into the modem like that.